# How do I use multiple user controls on an aspx page without making the same database calls in more than one control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, webforms

I'm currently on a project where each .aspx page is made up of multiple user controls (.ascx files). In some cases, more than one user control for a single page is making a call to the database for the same data. Two user controls might call the database for the same customer object to perform the tasks necessary to their individual circumstances. After all is said and done, some of the web pages end up making the same database calls 10 or more times because each user control needs the data for something it is doing. This does not seem efficient.

What are the best practices for handling this situation using ASP.NET Webforms? We have tried caching the database calls, but it just doesn't feel like a solid solution to the problem, although it has helped with performance. When using MVC, I can pass in a strongly-typed object containing all the data needed for a particular page, and the query for the data is only made one time. How do I achieve something similar using WebForms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practices are the same as for any OO programming: Don't Repeat Yourself.

In this case, rather than having the user controls query the database to get their data, have the data passed *to* the controls, through properties. You can even use data binding, just like a "real" server control.

BTW, there's nothing at all preventing you from passing a strongly-typed object to the user controls, just like you would in MVC:

In MyControl.ascx.cs:

```
public MyControlModel Model {get; set;}
```

Then just have the calling page set `Model` before the control data binds.

Comment: John, I had a feeling something like what you've described was possible, but you just confirmed that it is. That is great to know. Would you say that the .aspx page has a responsibility similar to that of an MVC controller in this case?

Comment: It's not formalized, but yes. I prefer to tell user controls what data they should display; gather any input data from them on PostBack, and then they can raise events when interesting things happen. Same pattern with user controls nested inside of user controls.